# QRCodeJs and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the following Library,
[qrcodejs](https://github.com/davidshimjs/qrcodejs)

I am using the library within React Frameworks and seem to be struggling. I get an error saying

> > Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

`<div id="qrcode" />` child

I've included a CodeSandbox example that yields the same result.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-shockley-41qom)

Thank you for taking the time to read! =]

Comment: Line 7 of your code is executed BEFORE the component is rendered, hence `document.getElementById("qrcode")` does not exist.

Comment: This package isn't really built specifically for react so you'll have to adapt it by creating and managing the `.qrcode` div yourself. Or you could just use a package that IS made for react such as this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode.react

Comment: @zerkms, gah of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated you've to adapt the code for React. In my approach I've used `useEffect` and `createRef` to abstract it: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-surf-d14of

```
function App() {
  const qrCodeRef = createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    new QRCode(qrCodeRef.current, {
      text: "hello",
      width: 166,
      height: 256
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div ref={qrCodeRef} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```